# Symfony2 get userID on kernel.controller event listener

Tags: security, symfony, event-listener

Can someone help me to get userID in event listener from event.controller?

```
#   EventListener
    kernel.listener.corporation.manage:
        class:  Site\CorporationBundle\Event\SiteCorporationManageListener
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@user.own.item", "@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelRequest }
```

And listener class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Site\MainBundle\Service\UserOwnItem;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SiteCorporationManageListener
{
    private $oEntityManager = null;
    private $oUserOwnItem = null;
    private $oSecurityContext = null;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $oEntityManager, UserOwnItem $oUserOwnItem, SecurityContext $oSecurityContext)
    {
        $this->oEntityManager = $oEntityManager;
        $this->oUserOwnItem = $oUserOwnItem;
        $this->oSecurityContext = $oSecurityContext;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST === $event->getRequestType()) {
            $route = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
            $corporationID = $event->getRequest()->get('corporationID', null);
            $userID = $this->oSecurityContext->getToken()->getUser()->getID();
            //$userID = 3;
            //var_dump($userID);

            if (strstr($route, 'corporation')) {
                if (!strstr($route, 'corporation_index')) {
                    $bUserOwn = $this->oUserOwnItem->setUserID($userID)->setItemType('corporation')->setItemID($corporationID)->userOwn();
                    //var_dump($bUserOwn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'll clean it later, i try different ways to do it, but even through container and security_context i cannot get userID. It brokes after getToken() method =.

At this example $userID is null... Even after getToken()->getUser() give me null...

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in /home/dev/public_html/git.eve-ceo/src/Site/CorporationBundle/Event/SiteCorporationManageListener.php line 32
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can get user id with this.

Include this.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
```

---

Here you get userId

```
$user = $this->oSecurityContext->getToken()->getUser();

if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
   throw new AccessDeniedException('You are not authorize to access this location.');
}
else{
    $userID = $user->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must use checking of token like this:

```
if ($context->getToken() && $context->getToken()->getUser() !== 'anon.')
    $user = $context->getToken()->getUser();
```

Basically you are not authenticated user.

Comment: I don't think that $context->getToken()->getUser() !== 'anon.' is really good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the same, but in symfony if you put "var_dump($user)" before you are logged in, the result is: string 'anon.' (length=5).
Maybe you can use "is_object($user) (for me is better option)

like:

```
if ($securityContext->getToken() && is_object($securityContext->getToken()->getUser())){
```

Answer (score 0):

For an update, service `security.context` is deprecated since Symfony 2.6.

So your new service declaration should looks like

```
#   EventListener
kernel.listener.corporation.manage:
    class:  Site\CorporationBundle\Event\SiteCorporationManageListener
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@user.own.item", "@security.token_storage"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Construct would be like

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

...

public function __construct(EntityManager $oEntityManager, UserOwnItem $oUserOwnItem, TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->oEntityManager = $oEntityManager;
    $this->oUserOwnItem = $oUserOwnItem;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

Then getting the user would become

```
$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```

source : http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue, where I posted an answer solving it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49794146/2564552

In short: Your Listener on `kernel.controller` is called before the Token is initialized, so you have to play with priorities or (in newer Symfony versions) just use the (not yet documented) `kernel.controller_arguments` event.