# Symfony 2.8: Cannot get current user in Service (FosUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to access the user inside a service in order to keep track of latest activity. However it throws an error:

> Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

but if I **var_dump** and **die()** the **user object** I can see the information.

Any ideas ?

**ActivityListener**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ActivityListener
{
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage     =   $tokenStorage;
        $this->em               =   $em;
    }

    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        if($user instanceof User)
        {
            $user->setLastActive(new \DateTime());

            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush($user);
        }
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
 app.activityListener:class: AppBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener
     arguments: [ @security.token_storage, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
     tags: - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144505/symfony2-get-userid-on-kernel-controller-event-listener

Answer (score 4):

As you can see here:

```
/**
 * Returns the current security token.
 *
 * @return TokenInterface|null A TokenInterface instance or null if no authentication information is available
 */
public function getToken();
```

`getToken()` can return TokenInterface object or **null** (when user is not logged in).

Change your method to this:

```
public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    if (is_null($token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken())) {
        return;
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();

    if($user instanceof User)
    {
        $user->setLastActive(new \DateTime());

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush($user);
    }
}
```

And if you see User object on  `var_dump` and `die()` then it must be the case when listener is called more times than one and then it don't have user information. Try to just echo something here to validate my theory (with echo before return). It can be connected with sub-requests and missing authentication data.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous person said, the code probably goes over the event listener multiple times. I'd check if the request is a master request, and if not, move on. After that, load the user from the token and check if it actually is a User object, because it could very well not be, if not, again move on.

```
public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest() || !$this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        return;
    }

    $user->setLastActive(new \DateTime());
    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush($user);
}
```