# Access current user in the kernel events [Symfony 4]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I wan't to save the navigation of my users.

I'm trying to save it from the `'kernel.request'` event but I can't get the current user ...

In my events listener :

```
KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['logNavigation0']
```

And the function :

```
public function logNavigation0(GetResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        dump(
            $event->getRequest()->getUser()
        );
    }
```

My user is connected, but `getUser()` return me `null`

How can I retrieve my User ? Is there another way to do that ?

Thanks !

My code :

```
class PlayerAction implements EventSubscriberInterface, LogoutHandlerInterface
{
    private $mailer;
    private $requestStack;
    private $entityManager;
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $sender;
    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, RequestStack $requestStack, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, $sender)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->sender = $sender;

        $this->serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // le nom de l'event et le nom de la fonction qui sera déclenché
            Events::PLAYER_REGISTERED => ['logSuccessRegistration'],
            Events::PLAYER_UPDATED => ['logSuccessRegistration'],
            Events::PLAYER_PLAYING => ['logPlay'],
            Events::PLAYER_WINNING => ['logWin'],

            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => ['logSuccessLogin'],
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE => ['logFailureLogin'],

            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['logNavigation0'],
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS => ['logNavigation1'],
        ];
    }
    [...]
    public function logNavigation0(GetResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        dump(
            $event->getRequest()->getUser() //Return null,
        );
    }

public function logNavigation1(FilterControllerArgumentsEvent $event): void
    {
        dump(
            $event,
            $event->getRequest()->getUser(), //Return null,
            ($event->getArguments()),
            $this->tokenStorage->getToken() //Return null,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you inject the `TokenStorageInterface` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 2.8: Cannot get current user in Service (FosUserBundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689081/symfony-2-8-cannot-get-current-user-in-service-fosuserbundle)

Comment: Try pass Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface as dependency injection and then call something like this $user = $tokenStorage->getToken() ? $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser() : null;

Comment: Are you in dev environment ? If so, is the toolbar showing you're connected as a specific user?

Comment: I try to inject the TokenStorageInterface, and it's the same result ... 

Yes, my debugbar show me my user.

Comment: Can you show us the whole event suscriber method?

Comment: @Cid Voilà ! :D

Comment: `dump($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());` instead of `dump($event->getRequest()->getUser());` ?

Comment: @Cid Null everywhere I call it ...

Comment: Can you show us then the firewalls section in `config/packages/security.yaml` ?

Comment: @Cid I got my answer ! I post my code in my question.

Comment: Please post your solution as **answer**

Answer (score 0):

I got my response !

The dev environment is too fast, I think ...

```
public function logNavigation(GetResponseEvent $event): void
{
    if(!empty($this->tokenStorage->getToken())) // In debug mode, it's null
    {
        /** @var Player $player */
        $player = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        if($player instanceof Player)
        {
            $playerHystory = new PlayerHistory();
            $playerHystory
                ->setLabel('NAVIGATION')
                ->setDetails([
                    'path' => $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo(),
                    'method' => $event->getRequest()->getMethod()
                ])
                ->setPlayer($player)
                ->setIp($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getClientIp())
            ;

            $this->entityManager->persist($playerHystory);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```